# Multiplying by pattern matching

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, pattern-matching

I have a matrix of the following format:

```
matrix = np.array([1, 2, 3, np.nan], 
                  [1, np.nan, 3, 4],
                  [np.nan, 2, 3, np.nan])
```

and coefficients I want to selectively multiply element-wise with my matrix:

```
coefficients = np.array([0.5, np.nan, 0.2, 0.3],
                        [0.3, 0.3, 0.2, np.nan],
                        [np.nan, 0.2, 0.1, np.nan])
```

In this case, I would want the first row in `matrix` to be multiplied with the second row in `coefficients`, while the second row in `matrix` would be multiplied with the first row in `coefficients`. In short, I want to select the row in `coefficients` that matches row in `matrix` in terms of where `np.nan` values are located.

The location of `np.nan` values will be different for each row in `coefficients`, as they describe the coefficients for different cases of data availability.

Is there a quick way to do this, that doesn't require writing if-statements for all possible cases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Approach #1**

A *quick* way would be with [`NumPy broadcasting`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) -

```
# Mask of NaNs                        
mask1 = np.isnan(matrix)
mask2 = np.isnan(coefficients)

# Perform comparison between each row of mask1 against every row of mask2
# leading to a 3D array. Look for all-matching ones along the last axis.
# These are the ones that shows the row matches between the two input arrays - 
# matrix and coefficients. Then, we use find the corresponding matching 
# indices that gives us the pair of matches betweel those two arrays
r,c = np.nonzero((mask1[:,None] == mask2).all(-1))

# Index into arrays with those indices and perform elementwise multiplication
out = matrix[r] * coefficients[c]
```

Output for given sample data -

```
In [40]: out
Out[40]: 
array([[ 0.3,  0.6,  0.6,  nan],
       [ 0.5,  nan,  0.6,  1.2],
       [ nan,  0.4,  0.3,  nan]])
```

**Approach #2**

For performance, reduce each row of NaNs mask to its decimal equivalent and then create a storing array in which we can store elements off `matrix` and then multiply into the elements off `coefficients` indexed by those decimal equivalents -

```
R = 2**np.arange(matrix.shape[1])
idx1 = mask1.dot(R)
idx2 = mask2.dot(R)

A = np.empty((idx1.max()+1, matrix.shape[1]))
A[idx1] = matrix
A[idx2] *= coefficients
out = A[idx1]
```

Comment: Could you explain what `mask1[:,None] == mask2` is doing?

Comment: @galliwuzz Added comments on it.